# Recommendations for Information Geometry in Machine Learning

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, machine-learning, information-geometry

I am fairly new to machine learning, but I have a 22-dimensional dataset, which I would like to increase the interpretability of by dimension reduction. I am relatively familiar with [principal component analysis (PCA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis), but I suspect a 22-dimensional space might be tricky to manage.

I've been told to seek guidance in [information geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_geometry), in order to find specific manifolds that would help me, for lack of a better expression, improve the categorization and dimensional reduction of my data. I was recommended the book [*Methods of Information Geometry*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Information-Geometry-Translations-Mathematical-Monographs/dp/0821843028), by Shun-ichi Amari, but I was wondering if you have any further reading recommendations to tackle such a problem. Thanks!

Comment: You might want to take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1587474/self-studying-information-geometry?rq=1